# Using 'to' in a PHP SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL query is `SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to = '$user_id' AND client_id = '001' LIMIT 4`
For some reason that query gives me the following error:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to = '1' AND client_id = '001' LIMIT 4' at line 1`
I used a different row and the query ran perfectly fine - is the error because of the word "to"? Or is there something else behind this?

Just for your reference, here's the PHP:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$client_id = '001';
if (!$query = sql("SELECT * FROM arrowchat WHERE to = '$user_id' AND client_id = '$client_id' LIMIT 4")) {
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
    echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: Try to quote `to` in backticks:  ``WHERE `to` = '$user_id'``.

Comment: Cannot believe I missed this rookie mistake. Thanks for the prompt responses people, been staring at this for about 2 hours now.

Comment: Rather than live the rest of your life having to quote `to` because it's a reserved word, change the column name.

Comment: @AndyLester The only problem with that is, there's a script already in place using `to` - so I'd have to change the variable numerous times.

Comment: short term pain for long term gain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

`to` is a reserved keyword in mysql, you cannot use it as is in a query. You need to wrap it in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `to` = '$user_id' AND client_id = '001' LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 3):

`to` is reserved mysql keyword you need to use backticks like that :

```
     SELECT * FROM arrowchat WHERE `to` ....
```

[reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)